# Trouble with integration using the definition of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm playing with integration for the first time and I can understand now why everyone tells me calculus II is the hardest calculus. I'm trying to solve this problem but I think I have the wrong answer, could somebody follow my steps and explain where I screwed up?

**Use the deﬁnition of the definite integral to evaluate the integral: $\int_0^2(2-x^2)dx$**

Here are my steps:
$$\lim_{n->\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f\left(\frac{2i}{n}\right)\frac{2}{n}$$

$$\lim_{n->\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n [2 - \left(\frac{2i}{n}\right)^2](\frac{2}{n})$$

$$\lim_{n->\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4}{n} - \frac{8i^2}{n^3}$$

$$\lim_{n->\infty}n\left(\frac{4}{n}\right) - \frac{8}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\left(i^2\right)$$

$$\lim_{n->\infty}4 - \frac{8}{n}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

$$\lim_{n->\infty}4 - \frac{8n^2}{3} + 4n + \frac{4}{3}$$

$$-\infty$$

It seems to me that negative infinity is not a logical answer. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Looks like I messed up, I fixed the equation and ended up getting $\frac{4}{3}$ as my answer.

Comment: 4th egality, it should be $\frac{8}{n^3}$ and not $\frac{8}{n}$

Answer (score 7):

In your third to last equation, you changed $n^3$ to $n$; your limit ought to read

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 4 - \frac{8}{n^3} \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$$

which is not negative infinity.